# Is every continuous function antiderivative of some function?

Tags: real-analysis

In other words, can we say that for any continuous $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\exists f$ such that $F(x) = \int_{0}^x f(s)\, ds$?

Comment: Not true. Indefinite integral of integrable functions have a stronger property: they are absolutely continuous.

Comment: @Bernard, fixed. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a counterexample. It is continuous but not absolutely continuous. It is differentiable (with derivative zero) almost everywhere, yet it increases from $0$ to $1$ on the interval $[0,1]$. So the only function it could be the antiderivative of is zero, which obviously is not the case.

Comment: So if I extend the cantor function by having f(x) = 0  for x<0 and f(x) =1 for x > 1, then that function would be defined on the whole of Real Numbers, but still won't be an antiderivative of any function. Right?

Comment: @user1752323 yep